# Http get problems in ISS/angular

Tags: angular, rest, iis, server

I have an angular production version deployed on my IIS server that's accessible through localhost:80/myApp aswell as externally by anyone.

It makes a get request using the url localhost:8080/datalist   to populate a page as the database is hosted on another server and I use software (Rocket u2) to access that server, I can see the data when I go onto localhost:8080/datalist so I know I'm connected to that server.

When I run my app on localhost 80 it populates the page no worries but when I run it through an outside computer that access the angular server but has no access to th database server I get a few errors.

First a CORS error that I have tried to enable in the Web.config file but I still get a yellow notification.
And I also get an error name not resolved for the localhost:8080

Is there a different way that angular needs to be set up to be able to get data like this or is it in the iis server setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of things that can be happening that would make these errors appear. I had similar issues at some point and here are the things I would check first if I was you.

1. CORS will not trigger on certain request types. Try to set your ContentType to 'application/json' in your HttpHeaders for your get request.
2. Make sure you have an appropriate config for the web.config of your site in IIS. It needs url rewrite. I put you mine at the end of the post for reference.

A good tool for checking what is going on and figure where it's failing is :[Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

One other handy chrome extension to test if the issue is only CORS related is [Moesif chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc)

It would also probably help you to figure where the issue can be if you read about CORS a little if you do not know what the technology is about. Here is a good reference for it: [Mozilla Developper Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Good luck with this Sam, it might be a little overwhelming at the beginning, but you'll get trought it ;)

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```